# ArcGIS - Serve data as tiles

Tags: arcgis-server

I have ArcGIS Server Basic Enterprise Version 10.3.1 and a Enterprise Geodatabase in Oracle 12c.

I want to create a service which will serve data from a view as tiles (PNG, JPG, whatever).

What type of service should I create?

Edit for more information:

I need to display a road network on top of a baselayer (google maps, OpenStreetMaps, etc) in a Web Application (.NET Core) using the ESRI Leaflet library. My netowrk consists of about 20000 links and it is stored in an Oracle database table.

I have already made a Feature Access Service, but because of the magnitude of data, the resulting response is huge (over 20MB) and cannot be handled by the browser adequately.

Since I have accomplished a similar task in the past using the Open Source MapServer, I am thinking about the following approach with ArcGIS Server:

Instead of returning a huge geoJson response, I think it would be better to configure the service in order to return tiles (PNG/JPG/whatever) with the links, therefore mitigating the load.

While the road network will always be the same, the "coloring" of the links will vary according to user preferences. For example, one user will might want to "color" the links according to "Vehicles Per Hour" during Summer of 2014, and some other user will might want to "color" it according a projection for Winter of 2020 (tha calculations will be performed by another module and the results will be stored in Oracle. I have already created a database View for properly quering the database. On this view I have based the existing Feature Access Service).

So, to cut a long story short, I cannot create a cached map beforehand; I'd rather like to create some sort of "dynamic" tiles, upon each request. This is something that I know (by first-hand experience) MapServer can do easily. Can ArcGIS Server Basic Enterprise behave the same way too?

Comment: ANY map service will produce the maps you want. I'd recommend training, since this is a **huge** topic.

Comment: I edited the question, I think it's not too broad anymore

Comment: Rather than asking a Boolean question, please attempt to accomplish your goal, then provide details of what you have tried and what error you have encountered. This is a basic capability of ArcGIS Server, but your licensing may  only support enterprise geodatabase, so that's where I'd recommend you place the initial research effort.

Comment: Since this has been closed, I cant put a real answer. But that answer is NO. Server basic cannot make cached map services per: http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf (page 11/ 23)

Comment: Nor can a Server install with a Basic license create ***any*** MapServer at all, as per the doc, so no, you can't generate maps with your current software.

Answer (score 2):

You can create Cache map service on ArcGIS. Here is the tutorial about how to create cache service in ArcGIS

http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/tutorial-creating-a-cached-map-service.htm

You need to enable your service as cache while publishing. You can select any tiling scheme available or you can use your custom tiling scheme in Service Editor Window.

Here is video demonstration about it as well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cU_yu3FpD2Q

Comment: thanks, I edited the original question to add more information